# angularjs dynamic select with json array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, httprequest

i'm developing an app where i should retreive from the server a JSON array through the http.get method.

The structure of the array is this:

```
[{
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "09:45"
  }, {
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "16:50"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "11:25"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "12:30"
  }, {
    "day": "21/11/2016",
    "time": "16:10"
  }, {
    "day": "21/11/2016",
    "time": "17:25"
  }]
```

From this array i should create a form with two selects where in the first i've days (for example 17/11/2016, 18/11/2016, 21/11/2016) and in the second i should have times "belonging" at days (for example 09:45, 16:50 OR 11:25, 12:30 OR 16:10, 17:25).

I think that i've found the solution at this problem but when i tried to run the project selects are always empty but the console tell me no errors.

This is my code,

**HTML**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="demo">
      <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Event Date</label>
          <select ng-options="event as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.event">
            <option value="">Select</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Event Time</label>
          <select ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules | filter: { date: ctrl.event.date}" ng-model="ctrl.schedule" ng-disabled="!ctrl.event">
            <option value="">Select</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**:

```
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .factory('dataService', dataService);

DefaultController.$inject = ['dataService'];

function DefaultController(dataService) {
  var vm = this;

  getEvents();

  function getEvents() {
    return dataService.getEvents()
      .then(function (data) {
        vm.data = data;
        return vm.data;
      });
  }
}

dataService.$inject = ['$http'];

function dataService($http) {
  var service = {
    getEvents: getEvents
  };

  return service;

  function getEvents() {
    var config = {
      transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
        if(headers("content-type") === "application/json; charset=utf-8" && angular.isString(data)) {
          var result = {
            events: [],
            schedules: []
          };

          var events = JSON.parse(data);
          var dates = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
              var date = events[i].day;
              dates.push(date);
              result.events.push({
                date: date
              });
            }

            result.schedules.push({
              date: events[i].day,
              time: events[i].time
            });
          }

          return result;
        } else {
          return data;
        }
      }
    };

    return $http.get('events.json', config)
      .then(getEventsCompleted)
      .catch(getEventsFailed);

    function getEventsCompleted(response) {
      return response.data;
    }

    function getEventsFailed(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Than'ks

Comment: i think your problem in `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes`. for this you need to check your url where you are getting json data

Comment: check this, it worked for me http://plnkr.co/edit/j4LVfFqIGPb1wNeHzpoB?p=preview

Comment: not for me.....

Comment: in the console i see the array and then tell me this error: **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

Comment: could you please clear your browser.

Comment: how? the chronology?

Comment: i've also tried my code on plunker and it works, this is the link: https://plnkr.co/edit/S6EGQ9maEGL10hOcAH9T?p=preview

Comment: @Sam here https://plnkr.co/edit/S6EGQ9maEGL10hOcAH9T?p=preview it works

Comment: then i think problems is your code can't getting json resource. if you are using json file then please put absolute path for testing purpose. whether it is working or not. could you please share your project structure ?

Comment: C://xamp/htdocs/HTTPget/index.html this is the path and script.js and events.json are in the same folder of index.html @Sam

Comment: `C://xamp/htdocs/HTTPget/events.json` put this path and check whether it is working or not

Comment: @Sam yes, it's working

Comment: could you please try `/events.json` or `./events.json`

Comment: in script.js? @Sam

Comment: yes, in script where you have mentioned `return $http.get('events.json', config)`

Comment: @Sam ok, now i try

Comment: @Sam nothing, the result is the same...

Comment: ok, i am trying your code, give me some time

Comment: @Sam ok, thank's a lot

Comment: You need to actually run a webserver, and make the get request to a URI on that server, rather than making the get request to a file

Comment: now i'm using xampp and the http.get method isn't a good idea? @Sam

Comment: yes you can use it.

Comment: @Sam so how can i solved this problem?

Comment: i think if you have tomcat server then put your json file in webapp folder and start the server and put the url in `return $http.get('events.json', config)`, i think it will work

Comment: now i don't use tomcat, i should use it? @Sam